# Headphones 3.5 jack stopped adding headphones as sound output device on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: sound, troubleshooting

My laptop is Thinkpad E480. I was able to use headphones up until a few hours ago.
My built in speakers played sound on really low volume so I enabled over-amplification on sound settings.
Ever since then when I plug the headphones to the 3.5 jack there is not effect and playback  continues only on built in speakers, not headphones.
Sound output devices show only speakers.
input michrophone though changes from "internal microphone - built-in audio" to "microphone - built-in audio" and shows mic activity.
Headphone are working fine on other devices.

This is clearly an ubuntu software issue.

Tried reinstalling pulseaudio and alsa but no effect.

Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

Turns out completely shutting down the laptop solved it. Rebooting or logging out/in was not enough.